# Error Importing Android Library into project Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am importing an Android Library into a new, fresh, blank Android Project in Eclipse.

When I select the library, everything is fine:

[image: Looking good!]

I right-click on the project again to check the library is still happily there...

[image: No good]

But it isn't and now I'm very sad.

Has anyone seen this problem before? I've tried cleaning both projects, I've tried reopening Eclipse, I've tried restarting my computer, I've tried rebuilding the library project from scratch. It's really starting to confuse me.

Thanks

Comment: is the eclipse is the C Drive ? if so try moving the library to the other drive

Comment: That was it. My workspace was on C:/, my Libs and Eclipse installation directories were both on D:/. I am flabbergasted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

Workspace, Installation and Libraries needed to all be located on the same physical drive. I guess this is a "feature" or nuance of Eclipse.

Thanks to AIL